# Can I display specific part of Output from Command Prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

If I run  `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` it will display,

> 1. Hosted network settings,
> 2. Hosted network status

these two parts.

But, if I want to display just the "Hosted network status" part, can I do that?

(It's like piping out specific part of the output, just to display the essential info to be displayed)

Comment: How much effort do you want to put into this? Technically it is possible, but the effort is very likely to be so much more than what it gains.

Comment: @LPChip It's a one line command ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to display just the "Hosted network status" part, how do I do that?

Use `for /f` from a command line:

```
for /f "skip=6 tokens=* usebackq" %a in (`netsh wlan show hostednetwork`) do @echo %a
```

Output:

```
Hosted network status
---------------------
Status                 : Not available
```

Notes:

- If the `for` command is in a batch file then replace all `%` with `%%`
- `skip=6` skips the `Hosted network settings` part of the output.

---

#### Further reading

- [FOR /F - Loop command: against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: Ah, this is a nice approach indeed. I've worked with FOR before, but not this detailed. I was thinking in using a cscript and manually filter the data out, hench my comment.

Comment: @LPChip I'm still learning how to use `for`, it is very powerful but hard to use :/

Comment: Indeed it is. :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you very much for your help :) and the reference link is helping a lot. I'm using these in some script (.bat) files, and displaying specific parts are crucial on those sometimes.

Comment: @MARUFSARKER http://ss64.com/ is good to bookmark ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill    yup, realized already :)

Comment: Slightly shorter: `for /f "skip=6 delims=" %a in ('netsh wlan show hostednetwork') do @echo %a`